# Link reports to Java? or Find means to apply BOLD format within Paradox 4.5?

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, paradox

I need to read reports in Java from Paradox but I don't know how to do this.  Can reports be imported through netbeans using a working driver?  I have linked tables to Java but not the reports.  I need to apply some Rich Text (ie. making a sentence BOLD - thus the need for the connection).  Do you have any suggestions as to how I can print BOLD if it is not possible to print BOLD using Paradox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Paradox 4.5 will not print BOLD as it is a 16-bit application and can't handle it.
I recommend to use a program like RaveReport as this has good connectability with Paradox specifically.  You would need create the forms from scratch and assign the labels you create to the relevent dataset.  You can apply RTF and graphics this way also.  It's a lot of work if you have many reports to build however it is a solution that will update the look of your reports compared to PDOX.

Good luck